# Laravel get Eloquent relation with default value if relation is not present?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, relational-database

I have a `Post` model , each post has many translations for example : `ru`, `fr`, `en` -  (`post_translations` table), The working code for getting all posts with a specific translations is like this (e.g. `fr`):

```
 $locale = 'fr';
 $posts = Post::with([
        'translations' => function($q) use($locale){
            $q->where('language', $locale);
        }
    ])->get();
```

But some of `$posts` does not have `fr` translation, all posts have `en` translation .

I want to get all posts with `fr` translation and for posts which does not have `fr` , return `en` translation!

Do  I have to do this manually? e.i. loop trough all posts and add `en` translation to those which does not have `fr`  or there is a laravel way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you write, I understand that Posts are always written in English and then translated in other languages.

I do not know the use you have to do about this, but I propose you to  query all the posts with French and English translations and then filter them while printing them

```
$locale = 'fr';
$posts = Post::with([
    'translations' => function($q) use($locale){
        $q->where('language', $locale);
        $q->orWhere('language', 'en');
    }
])->get();
```

Comment: Thank you, How to filter them in view? (blade)

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution to get all fr:

```
$posts = Post::whereHas('translations', function($q) use($locale){
    $q->where('language', $locale);
})->get();
```

Hope it help :)

Comment: Thanks! let me try

Comment: Does not work!  returns no translations  when there is no `fr`